# Facebook's graph api very slow when making multiple requests

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I'm trying to write a simple tracking system for several facebook campaigns we run (seven campaigns at the moment).
A key feature in this system is being able to see all the like counts of those pages in real time, so i wrote a simple php code to get the like count for each page from the graph api and I call it with ajax every few seconds.
The problem is the slow response from facebook, it takes around 2 seconds to get a response and can get up to 20 (!!!) seconds.
Here is the function I wrote to get the like count:

```
function getlikes($pageid){
echo json_decode(file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/" . $pageid . "?fields=likes"))->likes;
};
```

Is there any way around it? or the graph-api is just slow and i'll have to deal with it with some elegant solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i advise you to cache like counts somewhere on your server to make AJAX requests fast (and it'd be better if there are more than one client watching counts). on server side there should be a cron job updating the like count cache.

to speedup getting counts from Facebook you can make all requests to it in parallel with [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) multi-requests. if you are interested, take a look at the [rolling curl](http://code.google.com/p/rolling-curl/) library

Comment: Thanks, I had his idea in mind but it seemed over-complicated at that moment. 
I guess that there is no way around caching the like counts.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are caching the data so you're not re-requesting it every time someone views the page.

Distant second, to avoid setting up a new http connection for every request, you can use the batch API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a access token with this method, dunno why it doesnt work in my localhost, but from the graph explorer works pretty well

```
<?php
$pageids = array('xxxxxxxx');
$likes = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT page_id, fan_count FROM page WHERE page_id IN(". implode(',', $pageids) .")"));
?>
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: My function IS server side, it's written in PHP

Comment: seven at this moment, but it might get up to ten.